# Queries on Databricks with comparison to HDInsight Cluster

Tags: python, azure, databricks, azure-hdinsight, azure-databricks

I have few queries regarding Databricks implementation compared to HDInsight cluster.

1. Currently, few python files are running from /bin/ in the HDInsight cluster. Is there a way to upload the same python files to /bin in the Databricks.

   I am considering /FileStore/tables/ in the Databricks as same as /bin and have uploaded the python 
   files.

   Few files are getting executed but when there is a .sh script which refers to the PATH=.:PATH, it 
   fails there saying no script found.

   When I run the command as below in the Databricks python notebook,
   %sh PATH=".:$PATH"
   echo $PATH
   it gives, .:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin

   But I couldn't explicitly see those directories in the Databricks.

   My thought is explicitly defining the path in the bash script [ dbfs/FileStore/tables ] or is there a 
   better way of doing it.
2. In the bash script, how can I define the path explicitly where by actual scripts are present in the 
   Databricks.

   In the HDInsight cluster, it is pointing to /bin when it executes the bash script with PATH=.:PATH.

   Is there a way in Databricks to do the same.
3. Is there a way to change the Upload option to some other directories apart from /FileStore/tables 
   which Databricks is defaulting to.
4. In Databricks, is there a way to define [ like mount point to ADLS/ BLOB] mounting /FileStore/tables/ 
   as bin and uploading all python files to that path.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can set environment variables that you can access from scripts running on a cluster.

   - On the cluster configuration page, click the **Advanced Options**
     toggle.
   - Click the **Spark** tab.
   - Set the environment variables in the **Environment Variables** field.

[image]

2. You can also set environment variables using the `spark_env_vars` field in the [Create cluster request](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/clusters.html#clustercreatecluster) or [Edit cluster request](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/clusters.html#clustereditcluster) Clusters API endpoints.

3 & 4. FileStore/jars is a special folder within Databricks File System, where you upload libraries. More details, refer "[Databricks - Libraries](https://docs.databricks.com/libraries.html)".

Once, the jar files are uploaded to the FileStore/jars, you can call those libraries in the [init script.](https://docs.databricks.com/clusters/init-scripts.html)

Hope this helps.